# File css custom no working in odoo 13 (Control character zero width no break space)

Tags: odoo-13

I have a problem non width when adding file CSS custom in odoo 13, pls help me.

**File custom.css**

```
.o_main_navbar .o_menu_apps .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item{
    display: none;
}
```

**File assets web.backend XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend_common" name="Common Assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Maintain_Custom_Common/static/src/css/form-view-custom.css"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Maintain_Custom_Common/static/src/css/layout.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/Maintain_Custom_Common/static/src/js/show_lines.js"/>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

**Bug in web**

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p9b9.png

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add 'custom.css' file to your custom module. It's missing in your xml file.
Check these out to import your custom code correctly:
https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/css/main.html
https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-add-css-javascript-in-odoo